# Add custom fields for log4j2 JsonTemplateLayout with dynamic values only for error logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to write my java application logs in JSON format. I mainly have following requirements.

1. Need to add two additional fields into the log statement (severity & error code).
2. Values for those additional fields should be specified in the log statement (where we call log.error) - If the values are not specified it should print default values (should be able to set default values also)
3. Those fields should only available in error logs (should not applicable for debug, info and other logs)

So far I have read through documentations of log4j and found that the json format and additional field configurations can be done using `JsonTemplateLayout` provided by log4j (docs : [log4j-JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html)).

Here is my sample application code, log4j2.properties and pom.xml

Application code:

```java
package com.vajira.test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {
    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile","/home/vajira/test_projects/log4j2_test/src/main/resources/log4j2.properties");

        log.info("Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample info message");
        log.debug("Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample debug message");
        log.error("Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample debug message");
    }
}
```

log4j2.properties

```
monitorInterval=20

appenders = APP_CONSOLE

appender.APP_CONSOLE.type = Console
appender.APP_CONSOLE.name = APP_CONSOLE
appender.APP_CONSOLE.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.APP_CONSOLE.filter.threshold.level = DEBUG

appender.APP_CONSOLE.layout.type = JsonTemplateLayout
appender.APP_CONSOLE.layout.eventTemplateUri = classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json
appender.APP_CONSOLE.layout.eventTemplateAdditionalField[0].type = EventTemplateAdditionalField
appender.APP_CONSOLE.layout.eventTemplateAdditionalField[0].key = aNumber #should have these fields only for error logs
appender.APP_CONSOLE.layout.eventTemplateAdditionalField[0].value = 1
appender.APP_CONSOLE.layout.eventTemplateAdditionalField[0].format = JSON


loggers = app

# Log to console and rolling file
logger.app.name = com.vajira.test
logger.app.level = DEBUG
logger.app.additivity = false
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref = APP_CONSOLE

rootLogger.level = ERROR
rootLogger.appenderRef.APP_CONSOLE.ref = APP_CONSOLE
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j2_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-layout-template-json</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>2.17.1</log4j.version>
        <jackson.annotations.version>2.12.4</jackson.annotations.version>
        <jackson.databind.version>2.12.4</jackson.databind.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

This prints the following,

```
{"@version":1,"source_host":"vajira","message":"Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample info message","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2022-01-09T20:30:31.590+0530","level":"INFO","logger_name":"com.vajira.test.Main","aNumber":1}
{"@version":1,"source_host":"vajira","message":"Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample debug message","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2022-01-09T20:30:31.591+0530","level":"DEBUG","logger_name":"com.vajira.test.Main","aNumber":1}
{"@version":1,"source_host":"vajira","message":"Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample debug message","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2022-01-09T20:30:31.592+0530","level":"ERROR","logger_name":"com.vajira.test.Main","aNumber":1}
```

Expected output will looks like follows,

```
{"@version":1,"source_host":"vajira","message":"Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample info message","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2022-01-09T20:30:31.590+0530","level":"INFO","logger_name":"com.vajira.test.Main","aNumber":1}
{"@version":1,"source_host":"vajira","message":"Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample debug message","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2022-01-09T20:30:31.591+0530","level":"DEBUG","logger_name":"com.vajira.test.Main","aNumber":1}
{"@version":1,"source_host":"vajira","message":"Helllllooooooooooo this is a sample debug message","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2022-01-09T20:30:31.592+0530","level":"ERROR","logger_name":"com.vajira.test.Main","aNumber":1, "severity":<default-severity>, "err_code":<default_error_code>}
```

Can someone help me to achieve my above requirements with this??

Comment: Use a [`ThreadContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) to add additional data to your log messages.